# probability distribution with infinite variance but finite mean

Tags: probability-distributions

Does such a distribution exist?
The Cauchy distribution has infinite variance but its mean is also undefined.

Comment: Look up "power law": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law .

Comment: This is more suitable for math.stackexchange.com than here. 

Comment: Math questions posted here are supposed to be research questions, whereas this is more the sort of thing found in textbooks.

I suspect you'll be back with more questions of the former kind.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the density function $f(x)= (3/2) x^{-5/2}$ on the interval from $1$ to infinity.

More generally, Google for the term "Pareto distribution".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Pareto distribution for suitable parameter values, the t-distribution has a mean of 0 if the number of degrees of freedom is more than 1, but has infinite variance if it is not more than 2.